# Resolution of $(f=0)$ where $f(x,y,z)=x^ay+y^az+\omega z^ax$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity, blowup

Let $u\geq 2$ be an integer, $a=3u-1$, $\omega=e^{2\pi i /3u}$, and let $f$ be the polynomial $f(x,y,z)=x^ay+y^az+\omega z^ax$.

In Example 23 of https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/pamq/2008/0004/0002/PAMQ-2008-0004-0002-a001.pdf (p.217), it is written that: The singularity $(f = 0)$ can be resolved by $1$ blow up. The exceptional curve $C$ is smooth of genus $\binom{a}{2}$.

I am trying to understand and prove this statetment.

1. Does this mean the following: If $g:S'\to S=\{f=0\}$ is the minimal resolution of the isolated singularity at the origin of $S$ then $g^{-1}(0)$ is a curve of genus $\binom{a}{2}$?
2. If 1 is right, how can we show this? (A reference request to look up is enough. Actually I only know the algorithm for resolving an isolated surface singularity when the singularity is "simple", for example rational double points)

Comment: Do you know some properties of a blow-up? The blow-up here has exceptional divisor isomorphic to the projective plane curve defined by your equation: this curve has degree $ d= a+1 $. Therefore it has genus $ (d-1)(d-2)/2 = a(a-1)/2 $.

Comment: @CraniumClamp In here does the blow-up means the blow-up of $\Bbb C^3$ at $0$? or the blow-up of $f^{-1}(0)$ at $0$?

Comment: The blow-up of the zero locus, of course, that's $ f^{-1}(0) $. The blow-up is just the restriction of the tautological line bundle of $ \mathbb{P}^2 $ to the projective plane curve $ V(f) $.